# I want to submit this form into DB php

Tags: php, checkbox

i want to insert this below given form data to database, but i dont know how to do this, it is about inserting product to multiple warehouse with different quantities, when checkbox against the warehouse name is checked than the quantity textbox appears.

and this is my PHP code

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="product_insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="274" align="right" height="25"><strong>Product Name :</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="wproname" value=""  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="274" align="right" height="25"><strong>Select Warehouse :</strong></td>
      <td width="500"><table style="border:none">
          <tr >
            <td> Select </td>
            <td> Name </td>
            <td> Quantity </td>
          </tr>
          <?php 
    $sql="select * from tbl_warehouse where w_flag='1'"; 
    $result=ExecuteGetRows($sql);   
    $num_rows=count($result); ?>
          <?php for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++){ ?>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk<?php echo $result[$i]['w_id'];?>" value="<?php echo $result[$i]['w_id'];?>" id="chk<?php echo $result[$i]['w_id'];?>" onChange="display<?php echo $result[$i]['w_id'];?>();" />
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $result[$i]['w_name'];?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty<?php echo $result[$i]['w_id'];?>" id="qty<?php echo $result[$i]['w_id'];?>" style="display:none" />
             </td>
          </tr>
          <script>
function display<?php echo $result[$i]['w_id'];?>()
{
if(document.getElementById("chk<?php echo $result[$i]['w_id'];?>").checked)
{

document.getElementById("qty<?php echo $result[$i]['w_id'];?>").style.display="block";
}
if(!document.getElementById("chk<?php echo $result[$i]['w_id'];?>").checked)
{
document.getElementById("qty<?php echo $result[$i]['w_id'];?>").style.display="none";
}
}
</script>
          <?php } ?>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td align="right"></td>
      <td width="296"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add New" align="middle" class="button login_btn"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And I am using this php code for inserting data to the database

```
$sqls=mysql_query("select * from tbl_warehouse");
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($sqls)) {
    $w = $result['w_id'];

    echo $_POST['chk'.$w];

    foreach($_POST['chk'.$w] as $key=>$val) {
        echo $_POST['chk'.$w];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_product(p_id,w_id,p_name,p_qty) values ('','".$wid."','".$wproname."','".$qty."')"; 

        mysql_query($sql);  
    }
}
```

Comment: We are not here to give you a result ;) what have you tried on your own? What problem do you have?

Comment: i have asked only suggestion, i havent asked to make submit page for me, I havent worked with these type of multiple checkboxes, SO i just want some help @Stony

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: now check the question again, i have put the insert code @Stony

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the leading comma in your values list in your insert statement. So change this:

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_product(p_id,w_id,p_name,p_qty) values ('','".$wid."','".$wproname."','".$qty."')";
```

To this:

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_product(p_id,w_id,p_name,p_qty) values ('".$wid."','".$wproname."','".$qty."')";
```

Comment: this is not the issue, but thanks for your reply, and I have solved my problem @Drew Rush